# Регулярное выражение (регистр первого символа)

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, javascript

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, имеется регулярное выражение:

```
$('#title').val($('#title').val().toLowerCase().replace(/^(.)|(\s|\-)(.)/g,function(c){
```

return c.toUpperCase();
}));

Выполняется преобразование текста вида: "artist artist - song (feat. artist)" в вариант: "Artist Artist - Song (feat. Artist)". Функционирует отлично, за исключением, что первый символ возле скобки не изменяет регистр. В точности также ситуация, если, к примеру, текст: "[artist] - song", – преобразование происходит в вариант: "[artist] - Song" (в квадратных скобках символ не изменяет регистр).

Битый час пробуется применить различные вариации, но не удаётся найти подходящий вариант. Возможно, имеется решение? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $('#title').val($('#title').val().toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|-|\s|\(|\[)(\w)/g,function(c){ return c.toUpperCase(); }));
```

Попробуйте так.

Comment: Решение именно таковое, как и требовалось. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Лучше выделить слово и изменить регистр первой буквы.
Этот результат можно получить таким выражением

```
.replace(/(\w+)/g,function(c){ return c.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+c.substr(1); })
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Уверен, пригодится и данное решение.

Answer (score 0):

А не проще ли использовать для такого CSS?

```
#title { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

Comment: Проще - не всегда лучше. Поисковики проиндексируют текст без стилей, и в выдачу попадет непрезентабельный текст.

Comment: Согласен. А если поисковики собирают тексты до выполнения js?